# Swift 4 split Data by other Data ([Uint8])

Tags: swift

I'm pretty new to Swift and I'm looking for a method to split a `Data` datatype into smaller chunks by another `Data`. I cannot find any suitable method in the Apple documentation. Every method (split, filter, index...) work by passing just a `UInt8`, but I need to pass a `[Uint8]`.

For example:

```
var data: Data = Data.init([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xAB, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xEE, 0xBB, 0x14, 0x24])
var separator: Data = Data.init([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01])
```

And I need to to something like `data.split(separator: separator)`.

Is there any suitable method for doing this or should I just iterate over the entire buffer?

Comment: It seems to me that the algorithm that splits a string by a string should generalize to splitting any sequence by another (repeatable) sequence. If it really isn't available, I'd consider suggesting it on the Swift Evolution forums.

Comment: On a side note: you can use `Data([...])` instead of `Data.init([...])`.

Comment: Thank you @zneak I have been looking for the method in Apple's docs and even here in SO but I can't find a suitable solution. Every method for quick-splitting is done receiving just a ```Uint8``` as the separator, not an array of them. Thank you for the clarification on the ```init()``` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of a built-in method. A possible solution is to call
 `range(of:)` repeatedly to find all occurrences of the separator data,
and append the chunks between the separators to an array:

```
extension Data {
    func split(separator: Data) -> [Data] {
        var chunks: [Data] = []
        var pos = startIndex
        // Find next occurrence of separator after current position:
        while let r = self[pos...].range(of: separator) {
            // Append if non-empty:
            if r.lowerBound > pos {
                chunks.append(self[pos..<r.lowerBound])
            }
            // Update current position:
            pos = r.upperBound
        }
        // Append final chunk, if non-empty:
        if pos < endIndex {
            chunks.append(self[pos..<endIndex])
        }
        return chunks
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let data = Data(bytes: [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xAB, 0x02, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xEE, 0xBB, 0x14, 0x24])
let separator = Data(bytes: [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01])

let chunks = data.split(separator: separator)
for chunk in chunks {
    print(chunk as NSData)
}
```

Output:

```
<ab0203>
<eebb1424>
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin R. This could do the trick! Although I don't know how performant this could be, as this is going to make it several times a second with big Data streams.

Comment: @Jorge: I have changed it a bit. Now the chunks are *slices* of the original data, i.e. the data is not copied. Just be aware that the `startIndex` of a chunk is not necessarily zero anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the modifications @Martin R. That should be more performant. I have been thinking about this and to me is so weird there isn't a built-in method nor a library that could do this kind of chunking. Maybe you should upload a pod about Data chunking :D